# how to change user's shell current directory using python ? (ubuntu/linux)

Tags: python, shell, directory, cd

We can change the current directory in the shell :

```
username@hostname:~/f1$ cd ~/f2
username@hostname:~/f2$
```

is it possible to write a python (v2.7 and / or v3) which changes the current directory to one programatically determined ?

E.g.

```
username@hostname:~/f1$ python change_dir.py
username@hostname:~/f2$
```

Comment: It is not possible; a child process cannot change the environment of its parent. That's why `cd` is a shell built-in command.

Comment: Agree, it is just impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chepner and Sraw correctly said, *a child process cannot change the* current directory *of its parent.* So, what you can do is to let the Python program output the desired directory and use this output in a `cd` command:

```
cd `python print_dir.py`
```